# how to adjust "is a type but is used like a variable"?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, generics

I'm trying to generate some code in a web service. But it's returning 2 errors:

1)  List is a type but is used like a variable

2)  No overload for method 'Customer' takes '3 arguments'

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class wstest : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public List<Customer> GetList()
        {
            List<Customer> li = List<Customer>();
            li.Add(new Customer("yusuf", "karatoprak", "123456"));
            return li;
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        private string name;
        private string surname;
        private string number;

        public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
        public string SurName { get { return surname; } set { surname = value; } }
        public string Number { get { return number; } set { number = value; } }
    }
```

How can i adjust above error?

Comment: Use `new` keyword in front of `List` class

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is at the line

```
List<Customer> li = List<Customer>();
```

you need to add "new"

```
List<Customer> li = new List<Customer>();
```

Additionally for the next line should be:

```
li.Add(new Customer{Name="yusuf", SurName="karatoprak", Number="123456"});
```

**EDIT:** If you are using VS2005, then you have to create a new constructor that takes the 3 parameters.

```
public Customer(string name, string surname, string number)
{
     this.name = name;
     this.surname = surname;
     this.number = number;
}
```

Comment: +1, but the better solution to the second error message is to create a constructor that accepts the three arguments.

Comment: Your last statement assumes 3.0 of course, otherwise we have to assume he forgot to give us a constructor :)

Comment: @annakata: The same thought occurred to me!

Answer (score 4):

This

```
List<Customer> li = List<Customer>();
```

needs to be:

```
List<Customer> li = new List<Customer>();
```

and you need to create a Customer constructor which takes the 3 arguments you want to pass.  The default Customer constructor takes no arguments.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question:

You either need to create a constructor that takes the three arguments:

```
public Customer(string a_name, string a_surname, string a_number)
{
     Name = a_name;
     SurName = a_surname;
     Number = a_number;
}
```

or set the values after the object has been created:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.Name = "yusuf";
customer.SurName = "karatoprak";
customer.Number = "123456";
li.Add(customer);
```

Answer (score 0):

As all the properties in the `Customer` class has public setters, you don't absolutely *have* to create a constructor (as most have suggested). You also have the alternative to use the default parameterless constructor and set the properties of the object:

```
Customer c = new Customer();
c.Name = "yusuf";
c.SurName = "karatoprak";
c.Number = "123456";
li.Add(c);
```