# Load a gridview with a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I've got a list containing all the rows I want to display on my gridview. I get these rows from a datareader on my data layer, and once I've called the list up to the presentation layer, I'd like to bind the list results to the gridview. Is there any way to do this? Code below.

#### Data layer query and datareader to get all the data for the rows

```
public class SubmissionDatabaseService
{
    public List<Submission> GetAllSubmissions()
    {
        string Searchstring = "SELECT Submission.SubmissionId, Customer.CustName, Customer.CustCity, Customer.CustState, Broker.BroName, Broker.BroState, Broker.EntityType, Submission.Coverage, Status.Status FROM Submission INNER JOIN Broker ON Broker.BroId = Submission.BroId INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.CustId = Submission.CustId INNER JOIN Status ON Status.StatusId = Submission.StatusId";
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        List<Submission> lstSubmission = new List<Submission>();

        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand Searchcmd = new SqlCommand(Searchstring, conn);

        dr = Searchcmd.ExecuteReader();

        Submission tempSubmission;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            tempSubmission = new Submission();
            tempSubmission.setSubmissionId(dr.GetInt32(0));
            tempSubmission._Cust.setCustName(dr.GetString(1));
            tempSubmission._Cust.setCustCity(dr.GetString(2));
            tempSubmission._Cust.setCustState(dr.GetString(3));
            tempSubmission._Bro.setBroName(dr.GetString(4));
            tempSubmission._Bro.setBroState(dr.GetString(5));
            tempSubmission._Bro.setEntity(dr.GetString(6));
            tempSubmission._SubCov.setCoverage(dr.GetInt32(7));
            tempSubmission.setStatus(dr.GetString(8));

            lstSubmission.Add(tempSubmission);

        }
        return lstSubmission;
    }
}
```

#### Business logic layer

```
public class SubmissionService
{
    public SubmissionService() { }

    private Array _getllsubservice;

    public Array Getallsubservice
    {
        get { return _getllsubservice; }
        set { _getllsubservice = value; }
    }

    public List<Submission> getAllSubmission()
    {
        SubmissionDatabaseService sds = new SubmissionDatabaseService();
        return sds.GetAllSubmissions();
    }
}
```

#### Presentation layer

```
SubmissionService ss = new SubmissionService();
List<Submission> SubmissionsList = ss.getAllSubmission();`
```

Comment: You have only to show your data to a grid?

Comment: I'm also going to need for it to be sortable and searchable, actually. I figured I'd start with the basic problem and go from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To load data into a gridview just try:

```
yourgrid.DataSource=SubmissionsList;
yourgrid.DataBind();
```

Something useful here:

[How to Bind List<myclass> data with gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/934580/735864)

or here:

[Bind List to GridView](http://forums.asp.net/t/1109165.aspx/1?Bind+List+lt+gt+to+GridView)

Comment: Thanks dany, nice and simple.