# I try insert data in database using visual studio but I've got some errors

Tags: c#, asp.net

The values don't enter into database I add information but doesn't update the database server.

```
namespace InsertDatabase00
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter da;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PHOENIX\SQLEXPRESS1;Initial Catalog=Itzoz;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=True");
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into EmpData(Name,Email,Gender) values (@Name,@Email,@Gender)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change this line `SqlCommand cmd;` to `SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand();`

Comment: provide more details about the error

Comment: You need to declare your  `SqlCommand cmd,SqlDataAdapter da` outside in the form's scope where it's visible to all or atleast inside `button1_Click`, not just inside the `textBox1_TextChanged` scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to adjust "is a type but is used like a variable"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934479/how-to-adjust-is-a-type-but-is-used-like-a-variable)

Comment: Now the code is working but doesn't insert the new data in Sql server.

Comment: That is your second question.

Comment: I understand I will put a new question thank you .